how to access the looping value in foreach activity of elsa workflow in elsa designer?
I'm looping the foreach activity in elsa designer on a workflow variable, I want to use the looping element's value to be used in the subsequent activity. How can I access that? The activity inside the foreach body is the 'Send Signal' activity which I'm adding through the elsa designer.
Couldn't find how to access the looping variable
